# Link click count for animation to run once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I answered a question earlier to run a jQuery animation when a link is clicked. Then the poster asked quite a valid question which stumped me.

"How do you only run the animation on the 1st click"...

I thought this would be pretty simple, so I tried something like this:

```
clicked = true;

$('#hotel').click(function(){

    if (clicked){
    $('#Hotelbody').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
    $('#Hotelbody').fadeIn();
    $('#Mealsbody').hide();
        clicked = false;

    }
});
```

which, in all fairness, runs the animation only on the 1st click. But then if I clicked off that menu item and onto "Meals" for example, and return to click "Hotels" the animation doesn't run at all. I have spent the whole morning trying to figure this out, and I am getting frustrated now - haha

Essentially, what needs to happen is while the user is on "Hotels" menu item do not run the animation again if he / she clicks "Hotels" menu item. But if the user ventures to another menu item and returns to hotels, then run the animation.

Please see [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/8/) as an example.

Steps to follow:

```
1. Click Hotel --> (Animation runs)
2. Click Hotel again --> (Animation doesn't run)[so far, so good] 
3. Click Meals --> Then Click Hotels again --> (Animation will not run again)
```

Please let me know if I need to explain myself further?

**Thoughts:**
- Have jQuery look at css class :active and animate from that?

Comment: use [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method instead of click.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but one() will do exactly the same thing... It will run animation once, then when you return after the Meal menu item, it will do nothing? see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/9/

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to say!

Comment: DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/skhan/gMha8/12/

Comment: You'd have better to firstly handling correctly this `active` class, then logic is easy to get, check in click handler if element already active or not

Comment: the Hotel animation does not run because the Clicked variable is false forever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be that hard, just check if the one that's clicked is currently visible

```
$('#Hotel, #Meals').on('click', function(){
    var el = $('#'+this.id+'body');
    if ( el.is(':visible') ) return false;
    el.animate({width:'toggle'},1000)
    $('#Mealsbody, #Hotelbody').not(el).hide();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/16/)

Comment: SHEW - Mr 99.7k just steps in a blows my mind! :) This is excellent. Thank you sir. A lot smarter than the direction I was headed.

Comment: @Mike - No problem, mind blowing is what we do here !

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var lastClicked = null;

$('#hotel').click(function(e){
    if (lastClicked != e.target){
    $('#Hotelbody').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
    $('#Hotelbody').fadeIn();
    $('#Mealsbody').hide();

    }
    lastClicked = e.target;
});

$('#Meal').click(function(e){

    if (lastClicked != e.target){$('#Mealsbody').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
    $('#Mealsbody').fadeIn();
    $('#Hotelbody').hide();
                    }
     lastClicked = e.target;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/22/

Comment: Guess this is the only way we can accomplish it. I was thinking the exact same route, but also thought it was silly to have to reset flags each time. :( Thank you though.

Comment: @Mike I improved my answer.

Comment: wow - I actually like your method more, because I actually understand it!! haha

Comment: *slaps head* I didn't notice that the two click handlers were identical. If you use this, make sure you merge the two selectors as Adeneo does with his excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using classes http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/17/

```
$('.tabs_bar').on('click', '#hotel:not(.now)', function () {
    $(this).addClass('now');
    $('#Meal').removeClass('now');
    $('#Hotelbody').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 1000);
    $('#Hotelbody').fadeIn();
    $('#Mealsbody').hide();

});

$('.tabs_bar').on('click', '#Meal:not(.now)', function () {
    $(this).addClass('now');
    $('#hotel').removeClass('now');
    $('#Mealsbody').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 1000);
    $('#Mealsbody').fadeIn();
    $('#Hotelbody').hide();
});
```

---

Here's a stupid way to do it http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/14/

```
function meal() {
    $('#Mealsbody').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 1000);
    $('#Hotelbody').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 1000);
    $('#Mealsbody').fadeIn();
    $('#Hotelbody').hide();

    $('#hotel').off().on('click', hotel);
    $('#Meal').off('click', meal);
}

function hotel() {
    $('#Hotelbody').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 1000);
    $('#Mealsbody').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 1000);
    $('#Hotelbody').fadeIn();
    $('#Mealsbody').hide();

    $('#Meal').off().on('click', meal);
    $('#hotel').off('click', hotel);
}

$('#hotel').off().on('click', hotel);

$('#Meal').off().on('click', meal);
```

Comment: not stupid in my opinion, as this is the only way I thought of achieving it as well. Its almost exactly the same as Chris Hardies example, just a bit more elegant. haha

Comment: @Mike yeah, well got another one now using classes

Comment: @Mike you also may want to add `.stop()` to the animations

Comment: have a look at adeneo's answer.. I quite like that one :) Thanks so much for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#hotel').click(function(){

$('#Hotelbody').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
$('#Mealsbody').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
$('#Hotelbody').fadeIn();
$('#Mealsbody').hide();

});

$('#Meal').click(function(){
$('#Mealsbody').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
$('#Hotelbody').animate({width:'toggle'},1000);
$('#Mealsbody').fadeIn();
$('#Hotelbody').hide();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gMha8/11/)